# Time zone conversions

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, momentjs

I am having the start and end date as below,

Start Date: "2015-02-19T00:00:00-08:00"

End Date: "2015-02-19T17:00:00-08:00"

as you see the date format is in PST so the date is fine in PST time zone,the snippet i am using as below,

```
moment(StartDate).format("MMM Do");
```

but when i view the same page in IST [Indian Standard Time] it shows as below,

Start Date: "Feb 19th"
End Date: "Feb 20th"

Please help me out on this, let me know is there anything i am missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which IST?  Indian, Irish, Israeli?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are your original values:

```
Start Date: "2015-02-19T00:00:00-08:00"
End Date:   "2015-02-19T17:00:00-08:00"
```

These are the equivalent values in UTC:

```
Start Date: "2015-02-19T08:00:00+00:00"
End Date:   "2015-02-20T01:00:00+00:00"
```

These are the equivalent values in Indian Standard Time:

```
Start Date: "2015-02-19T13:30:00+05:30"
End Date:   "2015-02-20T06:30:00+05:30"
```

This is normal and expected behavior when adjusting time for time zones.  Two different positions on the globe do not necessarily observe the same calendar date at all times.

For further information about time zones, I suggest the following resources:

- [The timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) here on StackOverflow
- [The Wikipedia page on time zones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone)
- My [Date and Time Fundamentals](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/date-time-fundamentals) course on Pluralsight
- Visualization sites such as [worldtimebuddy.com](http://www.worldtimebuddy.com/) and [everytimezone.com](http://everytimezone.com/)
- Detailed time zone information at [timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/)

With regards to moment.js, if you are just saying that you'd like the original values to be retained (regardless of the user's time zone), then use the [`parseZone`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/) function.

```
moment.parseZone(StartDate).format("MMM Do");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make it without problems with [moment timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)

```
moment(StartDate).tz('America/Denver').format("MMM Do");
```

or any other city in PST-Zone...

Comment: Denver is Mountain time.  :)